# Do something while a process is running in python

Tags: python, performance, time

Do something else in between one process

I want to run a process in python and i want when the process took **more than 10** seconds, do something, such as *print(wait for it to finish.)*

this print must be printed **while process running**

If you know how can i do it in my code pls tell me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `thread` to multi thread your application.

e.g.:

```
import time
import threading

def long_running():
  print("long_running started")
  time.sleep(10)
  print("long_running finished")

x = threading.Thread(target=long_running)
x.start()
print("running something while long_running is running in background")
```

output (on REPL):

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May  9 2021, 14:00:28) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> import threading
>>> 
>>> def long_running():
...   print("long_running started")
...   time.sleep(10)
...   print("long_running finished")
... 
>>> x = threading.Thread(target=long_running)
>>> x.start()
long_running started
>>> print("running something while long_running is running in background")
running something while long_running is running in background
>>> long_running finished
```

output (when run from file):

```
$ python3 /tmp/a.py
long_running started
running something while long_running is running in background
long_running finished
```

Further reading about threading: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time module.

Here is a very basic example:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

m = 'hello world'
print(m)

for i in range(5):
    t1 = time.time()
    if t1 - t0 > 10:
        print('more than 10 seconds has passed')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('test', i)
```

There are other methods too, such as `threading`.